# PHP IntlDateFormatter format returns wrong date

Tags: php, date, format, intl

I'm getting incorrect results using IntlDateFormatter:

```
$dateFormater = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
'en_EN',
\IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
\IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);

$a = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',1332712800); //2012/03/26 00:00:00
$b = $dateFormater->format(1332712800); //March 25, 2012
```

But this only happens for dates between 2012/03/26 and 2012/10/28 and without hour (00:00:00).

I can't find out what is the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: works for me. cannot reproduce. Might be a timezone issue.

Comment: I found out the issue:

It is necessary to indicate the timezone, It seems that IntlDateFormatter does not take the timezone from php.ini, (like php date function).

Comment: manual says "Time zone ID, default is system default." though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone#TOC-Factory-Methods-and-the-Default-Tim says

> `TimeZone` maintains a static time zone object known as the *default time zone*. This is the time zone that is used implicitly when the user does not specify one. ICU attempts to match this to the host OS time zone.

In short, if you want to change the *default timezone* from intl to match what `date()` says, you must change the time zone on your operating system. But *don't do that*.

It is preferred that you specify the timezone in the call to `IntlDateFormatter::create()`. If you wish to use the default timezone that PHP is using elsewhere, that can be retrieved with [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_get).

```
$dateFormater = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
    'en_EN',
    \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    date_default_timezone_get()
);
```